# How to write Date and Time columns together in column as (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00) in output?

Tags: r, mean, lubridate, utc, mutate

I have various text files(with per minute data) in different folders in following manner. The start date of each file differs but the structure of each file is same as below:

```
Date/Time   Col1   Col2   Col3....
2021-01-01T00:00:00  20  12  34...
2021-01-01T00:01:00  .....
2021-01-01T00:02:00  .....
2021-01-01T00:03:00  .....
2021-01-01T01:04:00  .....
2021-01-01T01:05:00  .....
2021-01-01T01:05:00  .....
2021-01-01T01:07:00  .....
2021-01-01T02:08:00  .....
```

I have calculated every 15rows mean of my data (.txt file) using a code in R mentioned later. I want Date and Time column in a particular manner specified below. Time is in UTC format.

```
rep_TimeZ   Col1   Col2   Col3....
2021-01-01 00:00:00+00  12  36  56
2021-01-01 00:15:00+00  34  54  43
2021-01-01 00:30:00+00  24  23  21
2021-01-01 00:45:00+00  12  36  56
2021-01-01 01:00:00+00  34  54  43
2021-01-01 01:15:00+00  24  23  21
2021-01-01 01:30:00+00  12  36  43
2021-01-01 01:45:00+00  12  36  34
2021-01-01 02:00:00+00  12  36  34 
.
.
```

I am using following code in R to calculate 15rows average iteratively through different folders.

```
library(lubridate)

mn <- df %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "T")

cl <- c('C1', 'C3', 'C7')

mnf <- mn[ , cl ] %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.8) NA else 
  mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) 
 
mnf

write.csv(min, 'C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Test/15row.csv')
```

Can someone please help me in modifying the existing code to write Date and Time columns together in one column (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00) as shown above.

Comment: Because 7 is the mean of for minutes 1 to 15.

Comment: Ok...I see! But if I want minutes column to be written as 00 minutes or 15 minutes for the average of first 15 minutes, then 15 or 30 minutes for the average of next 15 rows..how can I do that?

Comment: This is just to make the reader understand that rows having Time column 00 means that the respective data pertains to the mean of first 15 row.s.and likewise for all other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply reformat the Time column, but i think it's better to do all in one go, and create the Time column in the way that you want, while you aggregate the data.

Additionaly, I made a different approach to define the groups `` as.numeric(`Date/Time`) %/% (15*60) `` instead of `as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))`. I think it makes what's happening more clear, but that's just my preference.

```
df %>%
  group_by(groups = as.numeric(rep_TimeZ) %/% (15*60)) %>%
  summarise(rep_TimeZ = rep_TimeZ[1],
            across(Col1:Col3, mean)) %>%
  select(-groups)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 200 × 4
   rep_TimeZ            Col1  Col2  Col3
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01 00:00:00 0.451 0.448 0.514
 2 2021-01-01 00:15:00 0.577 0.585 0.572
 3 2021-01-01 00:30:00 0.496 0.475 0.482
 4 2021-01-01 00:45:00 0.539 0.516 0.512
 5 2021-01-01 01:00:00 0.392 0.437 0.414
 6 2021-01-01 01:15:00 0.568 0.620 0.517
 7 2021-01-01 01:30:00 0.590 0.588 0.444
 8 2021-01-01 01:45:00 0.417 0.510 0.364
 9 2021-01-01 02:00:00 0.377 0.446 0.306
10 2021-01-01 02:15:00 0.613 0.614 0.501
# … with 190 more rows
```

**Dummy data:**

```
df = tibble(rep_TimeZ = seq(as.POSIXct('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), by = 60, length.out = 3000),
            Col1 = runif(3000), Col2 = runif(3000), Col3 = runif(3000))
```

Comment: Thanks but the code, in the end, is giving me this error: Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `groups = as.numeric(`Date/Time`)%/%(15 * 60)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'Date/Time' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred. How can I resolve it?

Comment: `Date/Time` is the name of the date time column in your original dataset (pre aggregation). The example you posted here had that name, but just change it to whatever is the actual name. Also, that column must be formated as date time, not character.

Comment: Is it possible to write it in the way I mentioned in the question i.e., only the starting time in the row and not as an interval like you mentioned. e.g. 00:00:00+00 in the first row, 00:15:00+00 in the second row and so on.. Please note that I have edited my question. The modification requested is: In the output, Date and Time should come in the same column with Column name as rep_TimeZ

Comment: Chek my edit @AlexiakBoston

Comment: Date column seems to work properly, thanks but the mean of other columns are not coming as expected. Also, you seem to have put a limit on sequence in df (dummy data), I do not want to keep any limits, because I need to run the code on various .txt files at once and each file has different starting time period and no.of records.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. What do you mean not coming as expected? And I don't understand what you mean by "limits on sequence"? Are any of these still a problem? @AlexiakBoston

Comment: It gives me the following error. Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `groups = as.numeric(rep_TimeZ)%/%(15 * 60)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'rep_TimeZ' not found. I have updated my code in the question. Could you please revise your code accordingly. Also, in the output, I want Time column as hh:mm:ss+00.